# Problem with aggregate in mongoDB to populate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

There are various pieces of information in the transaction model that are not required,
for example, We don't know if the transaction is registered for dealer or delivery, and if it is for either, the other is empty

```
    dealer: {
  type: SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Dealer',
  required: false,
},
delivery: {
  type: SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Delivery',
  required: false,
},
```

When I use aggregate, only data that has both dealer value and delivery is returned

```
 const aggregate = [
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'deliveries',
    localField: 'delivery',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'delivery',
  },
},
 {
  $unwind:"$delivery",
  },
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'dealers',
    localField: 'dealer',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'dealer',
  },
},
{
  $unwind: '$dealer',
}]
```

so, no data is returned
How can you do aggregate if there is a field in a document, it doesn't matter if it doesn't exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can `$unwind` with `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` set to `true` so that the document won't get removed if there is an empty array to unwind. Here is a [mongoplayground demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MCRWl6rKLe5)

```js
const aggregate = [
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "deliveries",
      localField: "delivery",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "delivery",
      
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$delivery",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "dealers",
      localField: "dealer",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "dealer",
      
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$dealer",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/kC27B_u6Krk this is what your initial query gives. you can see the intermediate results between each stage by selecting on the Stage dropdown on top